# How to add new python type translation to ExternalEvaluate?

Tags: external-calls, python

Seems like Mathematica can only import basic types (lists, numpy objects, etc). Is there a way to tell Mathematica how to understand arbitrary python objects?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

A class who **inherits the `WLSerializable` class** and **overrides the `to_wl` method** can be automatically converted.

```py
from wolframclient.serializers.serializable import WLSerializable
from wolframclient.language import wl
from wolframclient.serializers import export

class MyPythonClass(WLSerializable):
    def __init__(self, *arguments):
        self.arguments = arguments

    def to_wl(self):
        return wl.YourWolframFunction(*self.arguments)
```

[image]

So we can use a wrap type to implement automatic conversion:

```py
from sympy import Rational

class myRational(WLSerializable, Rational):
    def to_wl(self):
        return wl.Divide(self.p, self.q)
```

[image]

Here are some special binding packages, which can also be automatically converted: [WolframResearch/WolframClientForPython](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframClientForPython/blob/master/wolframclient/utils/api.py)

Comment: Could you add an example for working with a complicated data type like graphs or images please?

Comment: @well, which lib, expect matplotlib, it not use class

Comment: Nice and concise answer -- thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Developers say they provide an interface: [Extending Serialization Writing an Encoder](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/docpages/advanced_usages.html#extending-serialization-writing-an-encoder)

Using as follows:

[image]